# Data table JQuery with MVC Razor Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller, datatable

I hope you can help me.

I'm trying Datatable using JQuery but it shows me the following error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when I call the function:

```
     $ ('#tablaUsuarios').dataTable()
```

And load plugins needed

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables-1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
```

from the master page.

Add the following script to load the Data table but it shows me the error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when I call the function Datatable

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#tablaUsuarios').dataTable({  <----Here is the error
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "RegUsuarios/DataTableUsuarios",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sName": "Id",
            "bSearchable": false,
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                return '<a href=\"Details/' +
                            oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
            }

        },
        { "sName": "Nombre" },
        { "sName": "Correo" },
        {"sName":"Nombre de Usuario"}

        ]
    });
});
   </script>
```

And this is my html code

```
    <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="display" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
        <th>Empresa</th>
        <th>Rol</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
        <th>Empresa</th>
        <th>Rol</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of headache found the solution to my problem

Just added the jQuery variable `noConflict`

```
    var jquery = jQuery.noConflict();
      jquery(document).ready(function () {
      jquery('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```